# Multiple Styles of Rollover Links

Tags: html, css, rollovers

I'm sure this is a rather simple fix but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I used the page properties in Dreamweaver to come up with the CSS for the links on the page and everything was working correctly. I now have one row where I need to change both the link and hover colors for a few links.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
background-color: #666666;
}

a:link {
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: #000000;
}
a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #666666;
}
a:active {
text-decoration: none;
color: #000000;
-->
</style>
</head>
```

I was able to change the link color successfully by using the code below in the body.

```
<a href="url" target="_blank" style="color: rgb(20,80,153)">Website</a>
```

What I have not been able to do successfully is change the rollover. I've searched and tried a few different methods to solve the problem but haven't had any success. Could somebody point out what I'm doing wrong or give me an example of how the CSS should look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use class names instead of just targeting the `a`

CSS

```
a.someName1:link {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.someName1:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

a.someName1:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #666666;
}

a.someName1:active {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #000000;
 }
```

HTML

```
<a href="url" target="_blank" class="someName1">Website</a>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, I was sort of on the right track but tt really helps to see it spelled out. Thanks to everyone for the replies!

Comment: @JamesGGray no problem. Glad to help, just mark an answer off as correct

Answer (score 1):

So to colour the link you just need:

```
a{
    color: rgb(20,80,153);
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Then if its hover you want:

```
a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<a href="url" target="_blank">Website</a>
```

### CSS:

```
a{
    color: rgb(20,80,153);
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}
a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/5E9Tf/)

---

On top of that, if you do not want it for ALL links you give them a class:

### HTML:

```
<a href="url" class="test" target="_blank">Website</a>
```

### CSS:

```
.test {
  color: rgb(20,80,153);
}

.test:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/5E9Tf/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Give your special links a [special class](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/class.php):

**CSS**

```
.link
{
    color: rgb(20, 80, 153);
}

.link:hover{..}
.link:active{..}
.link:visited{..}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="link">Website</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to change the colors for a entire row would be to add a class to said row (or `<tr>`, I'm assuming) and then add CSS for all links that are descendants of a element with that class.

I'm making some assumptions on your HTML, but it will probably go something like this...

**HTML:**

```
<tr class="atl-color">
<td><a href="#">Link #1</a></td>
<td><a href="#">Link #2</a></td>
</tr>
```

**CSS:**

```
.alt-color a:link { color: blue; }
.alt-color a:hover { color: red; }
```

Comment: unless you are displaying tabular data you should never use table elements as a layout. If you want to use your concept you should instead wrap the links in a `div` and then target the `a` within that div

Comment: @jmore009 I understand that. The reason I am using tables in my example is because OP specifically mentioned the use of rows on his page, so I was assuming that he was using tables. No markup was given, and I needed a wrapping element to add my class to, so I made a assumption.